# Why my program.exe (made in Python) can't use new environment variable after it restarted?

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables

I am developing an executable with Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

My software needs to install 2 programs: the sdkmanager and the build-tools utilities.

**My main issue is to use the environment variables freshly modified.**

To install build-tools, I need first to install SDKmanager. When my code installs SDKManager, it is adding environment variables to make the program "sdkmanager.bat" available in the environment.

The first command my software is doing is "sdkmanager --list". When my program.exe run this command, it says "this program is not recognized and internal or external command". It is normal as my program.exe just changed the environment variable PATH and it needs to restart to use it.

So my program.exe start a new instance of program.exe. This 2nd program.exe detect the first program.exe and kill it in order to let only 1 program.exe running.

So this 2nd program.exe suppose to enjoy the new environment variable, but it is not the case.

I tried all the possible code to start new porgram.exe:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("start myprogram.exe", shell=True,stdin=None, stdout=True, stderr=None, close_fds=True)

os.system('start cmd /c  "myprogram.exe"')

proc = os.popen("start cmd /c myprogram.exe")

proc = subprocess.check_call(['myprogram.exe'], shell=True)

proc = subprocess.run(['myprogram.exe'])

ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", 'myprogram.exe', '', None, 1)

etc....
```

It didn't work. Each time my program can't run the command "sdkmanager --list" as it says "this program is not recognized and internal or external command".

What is weird is I am displaying the value of the environment variable PATH and I can see the path to the script sdkmanager.bat.

So I used different methods to propagate the new environment variables:

```
#Method 1
def RefreshEnvironment():
    #https://gist.github.com/apetrone/5937002
    HWND_BROADCAST = 0xFFFF
    WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A
    SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002
    sParam = "Environment"
    res1, res2 = win32gui.SendMessageTimeout( HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, sParam, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 100 )
    bool_res=bool(res1)
    if not res1:
        logger.info(f"result: {bool_res} {res2} from SendMessageTimeout")

#Method 2
def RefreshEnvironment(timeout_ms=2000):
    #https://programtalk.com/python-examples-amp/win32con.HWND_BROADCAST/
    """Broadcast a message to all top-level windows informing them that
    an environment change has occurred. The message must be sent, not posted,
    and times out after `timeout_ms` ms since some top-level windows handle this
    badly. NB This is a static method.
    """

    win32gui.SendMessageTimeout(
        win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SETTINGCHANGE,
        0, "Environment",
        win32con.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, timeout_ms
    )
```

But it didn't work.

**What is very weird, is when I restart program.exe manually myself by double clicking on it, it works! program.exe recognized the command "sdkmanager --list" when I run the program myself whereas it doesn't if program.exe restart itself. I don't understand.**

Does anyone already face this situation where your program has to restart to enjoy the environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is I didn't understand well how the environment works with python.

In fact, there are 2 environments:

1. The environment of the machine.
2. The environment of python loaded when Python starts.

I was changing with success the environment of my machine, but Python was keeping its own environment in its memory. So even if everything was updated in the environment machine, Python was ignoring it, even after restarting the program.

I had to use the module os.environ to load my new environment variable in the Python environment in order to let Python enjoy these new environment variables.

Here is the code I use now which is working from my side:

```
# After I change the environment variable, I use my function 'GetEnvVarSys' to get the environment variable from Windows registry
ANDROID_HOME=GetEnvVarSys("ANDROID_HOME")
JAVA_HOME=GetEnvVarSys("JAVA_HOME")
PATH=GetEnvVarSys("PATH")

# then I pass them to Python os.environment
os.environ['ANDROID_HOME'] = ANDROID_HOME
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = JAVA_HOME
os.environ['PATH'] = PATH
```